# Obtain all combinations for regex substitution of overlapping pattern

Tags: python, regex

My goal is to obtain all the possible substitution for all overlapping patterns of a given regex.

Normally when I want to obtain a substitution with regex I do the following

```
import re

re.sub(pattern='III', repl='U', string='MIIII')
```

and I would obtain the following output:

```
MUI
```

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) the substitution is done only on the **leftmost** match in case of overlap, but what I need is to obtain all the possible substitutions, which in this case are:

```
MUI
MIU
```

My goal is using it also for complex regex patterns like the following

```
re.sub(pattern="M(.*)$", repl="M\\1\\1", string='MIU')
MIUIU
```

I didn't find any solutions natively in the python standard library

Comment: `re.sub()` will only return one result.

Comment: `[source[:m.start()] + replacement + source[m.start() + len(pattern):] for m in re.finditer(f'(?={pattern})', source)]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght your solution works for the given case but fails for more complicated regex patterns like this pattern="M(.*)$" repl="M\\1\\1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way to implement this is to search for pattern *(using [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search))* until no match pattern found and replace just single occurrence of pattern *(using [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with `count`  argument)* slicing string every iteration to skip previous match.

```py
import re

source = "MMM123"
pattern = re.compile("M(.*)$")
replacement = r"M\1\1"

last_start = 0
temp = source
while match := pattern.search(temp):
    print(source[:last_start], pattern.sub(replacement, temp, 1), sep="")
    last_start += match.start() + 1
    temp = source[last_start:]
```